# Entity framework core 2.0 Functions how to work

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use entity framework core 2.0 functionality (custom functions db) in dbcontext.
I created the next method:

```
    [DbFunction]
    public static int fnGetZona(double latitudine,double longitudine) { throw new System.Exception(); }
```

If I call this method in my code `dbcontext.fnGetZona(latitudine,longitudine)` I get

> Exception of type 'System.Exception' was thrown

Which is the right way to use db's custom functions in entity framework core 2.0 and UWP 10?

Comment: Well, your code throws that error, see the body of your function: `throw new System.Exception();`

Comment: My db custom function return a int.

Comment: @dbraillon I guess that function map to my db custom function. Can you tell me how to implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call your function inside linq query like:

```
var test = (from r in context.SomeEntity
where r.Zona == DBContext.fnGetZona(lat, lon)
select r).ToList();
```

Also you are missing formal arguments for `DbFunctionAttribute`.

Comment: And schema to annotation method. Thanks